# Encrypt in SQL Decrypt in .Net - How i made it

Tags: c#, .net, sql, security, cryptography

I want to encrypt data on SQL-Server and decrypt it on a .NET application. The best way in my Situation was to use Certificates.

In my Test DB I had to create a Master-Key:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRPTION 
BY PASSWORD = 'TestEncryption1212'
```

Then I created a certificate on SQL-Server

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE TestCertificate1212
WITH SUBJECT = 'TestEncryption1212'
```

Next I exported it to the File-System:

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE TestCertificate1212
TO FILE = 'C:\temp\TestCertificate1212.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (
    FILE = 'C:\temp\TestPrivateKey1212.pvk',
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TestEncryption1212'
    )
```

If I add a

```
DECRYPT BY PASSWORD = 'TestEncryption1212'
```

I get an error which says that the Private Key is encrypted by the master password.

I encrypt a Collumn in my Test DB

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Encrypt
ADD EncryptedCol varbinary (256)

UPDATE dbo.Encrypt
SET EncryptedCol = 
    ENCRYPTBYCERT(
        CERT_ID('TestCertificate1212'),
        ClearTextCol
    )
```

so far, so good.

Next Step is to generate a PFX file which combines the certificate with the privatekey file

I change the directory in cmd to the folder where the pvk2pfx.exe is and execute it:

```
>cd "Program Files\Microsoft SDK
s\Windows\v6.1\Bin"
>pvk2pfx.exe -pvk C:\temp\TestPrivateKey1212.pvk -spc C:\temp\TestCertificate1212.cer -pfx C:\temp\TestPFX.pfx
```

In my .NET application (C#-ConsoleApplication)  I get the Data via an SqlConnection ..  I pass the data on to a Function which I called

```
public string DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(string pfxFilePath, byte[] EncryptedDocID)
```

This function should open the Certificate and decrypt the Data and return the clear Text back to the Application:

```
public string DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(string pfxFilePath, byte[] EncryptedDocID)
{
    string DecryptedDocID = "";
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath, "TestEncryption1212");
    if (cert == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Certificate " + pfxFilePath + " Does not exist");
    }
    if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        byte[] ret = RsaCSP.Decrypt(EncryptedDocID, true);
        if (ret == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Decryption with RSA failed");
        }
        DecryptedDocID = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ret);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Certificate " + pfxFilePath + " has no Private Key; ");
    }

    return DecryptedDocID;
}
```

When it comes to decrytion i get the Error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at TestDecryption.MyDecryptor.DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(String pfxFilePath, Byte[] EncryptedDocID) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\MyDecryptor.cs:line 57
   at TestDecryption.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\Program.cs:line 37
```

I am tired of searching for the error. Is there anybody out there who sees the error and can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I think it the problem is that the Private Key is encrypted with the Master Key and I can't decrypt it. I think all what i would need is an sql statement where I can set the password for the privat key without the Master Key ? Or am I on a completly wrong way?

Please help me!

---

**UPDATE**

If I make my Certificate outside SQL_Server with the command:

```
C:\temp\createCert>makecert -sv PrivateKey.pvk -n "cn=TestCertificate" TestCerti
ficate.cer -b 01/01/2013 -e 01/01/2014 -sky Exchange -pe
```

Run all my SQL Scripts again:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Encrypt
DROP COLUMN EncryptedCol

DROP CERTIFICATE TestCertificate1212
DROP MASTER KEY

CREATE CERTIFICATE TestCertificate
    FROM FILE = 'C:\TEMP\createCert\TestCertificate.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        FILE = 'C:\TEMP\createCert\PrivateKey.pvk',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TestEncryption123'
--      DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TestEncryption123'
    )

ALTER TABLE dbo.Encrypt
ADD EncryptedCol varbinary (256)

UPDATE dbo.Encrypt
SET EncryptedCol = ENCRYPTBYCERT(CERT_ID('TestCertificate'),SecondCol)
```

and then try to decrypt it I get several errors:

eighter I use

```
byte [] ret = RsaCSP.Decrypt(EncryptedDochID, true);
```

and get:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptPKWin2KEnh(SafeKeyHandle hPubKey, Byte[] key, Boolean fOAEP, Int32& hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb,Boolean fOAEP)
   at TestDecryption.MyDecryptor.DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(String pfxFilePath, Byte[] EncryptedDocID) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\MyDecryptor.cs:line 71
   at TestDecryption.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\Program.cs:line 37
```

Or I use:

```
byte [] ret = RsaCSP.Decrypt(EncryptedDochID, false);
```

and get:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle hPubKey, Byte[] key, Int32 dwFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
   at TestDecryption.MyDecryptor.DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(String pfxFilePath, Byte[] EncryptedDocID) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\MyDecryptor.cs:line 71
   at TestDecryption.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\Program.cs:line 37
```

or

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle hPubKey, Byte[] key, Int32 dwFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
   at TestDecryption.MyDecryptor.DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(String pfxFilePath, Byte[] EncryptedDocID) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\MyDecryptor.cs:line 71
   at TestDecryption.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\developmentUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestDecryption\TestDecryption\Program.cs:line 37
```

depending on the flag i set by makeCert (**-pe**)

my new Question is:

Is SQL-Server using RSA to encrypt Data with ENCRYPTBYCERT()????????????? Or am I trying the infeasable?

Yess, it seems that it is encrypted by RSA. [Michael Coles](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/michael_coles/archive/2010/01/29/encrypt-it-in-net-decrypt-it-on-sql-server.aspx) was making something very simular to mine and used RsaCryptoServiceProvider to Encrypt the Data in his .NET application. But he uses a stored procedure to decrypt the data. I don't want to decrypt the data on the server. I need to decrypt it also with RsaCryptoServiceProvider..

So the new Title should be: How can I get rid of my error?

---

**UPDATE:**
How can I decrypt the Data using RsaCryptoServiceProvider and a self made certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:
Created Certificate outside SQL:

```
Change Directory to cd "C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin"
copy makecert.exe and pvk2pfx.exe to temp\createCert\
C:\temp\createCert>makecert -sv PrivateKey.pvk -n "cn=TestCertificate" TestCertificate.cer -b 01/01/2013 -e 01/01/2014 -sky Exchange
```

created pfx file

```
C:\temp\createCert>pvk2pfx -pvk PrivateKey.pvk -spc TestCertificate.cer -po TestEncryption123
```

> - Yes, export the private key
> - Include all certificates in the certification path if possible
> - Export all extendend properties

Set password: TestEncryption123

choose Filename for pfx file...

ran this on SQL Server:

```
USE master 
GO
 
CREATE DATABASE TestEncryptionDecryption
GO
 
USE TestEncryptionDecryption
 
CREATE TABLE Encrypt 
(
    intCol int,
    clearTextCol varchar(128)
)
GO
 
INSERT INTO Encrypt (intCol, clearTextCol)
VALUES
    ('1', 'Links'),
    ('2', 'Zwo'),
    ('3', 'Drei'),
    ('4', 'Vier'),
    ('5', 'Fünf'),
    ('6', '5ech5')
GO
 
 
CREATE CERTIFICATE TestCertificate
    FROM FILE = 'C:\temp\createCert\TestCertificate.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        FILE = 'C:\temp\createCert\PrivateKey.pvk',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TestEncryption123'
    )
GO
 
SELECT * FROM sys.certificates
 
 
ALTER TABLE Encrypt
ADD 
    encryptedCol varbinary (128)
GO
 
UPDATE Encrypt
SET
    encryptedCol = ENCRYPTBYCERT
    (
        CERT_ID('TestCertificate'),
        clearTextCol
    )
GO
 
 
DECLARE @Passwd nvarchar(128) = 'TestEncryption123'
SELECT intCol,
    clearTextCol,
    encryptedCol,
    CAST
    (
        DECRYPTBYCERT
        (
            CERT_ID('TestCertificate'),
            encryptedCol,
            @Passwd
        ) AS varchar(128)
    ) AS decryptedCol
FROM dbo.Encrypt

GO
```

made my Testprogram:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
 
namespace Testbeispiel_Encryption
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create a new instance of MyDecryptor
            MyDecryptor Decryptor = new MyDecryptor();
            //not recommended to store password as a cleartext (but for development purposes ;) 
            string password = "TestEncryption123";
            System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
            //create Secure Password
            foreach (char keyChar in password.ToCharArray())
                securePassword.AppendChar(keyChar);
            //Insert Connection String (local because I am working on the Server)
            string constr = "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=TestEncryptionDecryption;INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI;";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                //Open the connection to the initial catalog
                con.Open();
                //create SELECT statement
                string cmdstr1 = "SELECT intCol, clearTextCol, encryptedCol FROM dbo.Encrypt";
 
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr1, con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    //now we read data
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.Write(reader[0] + "\t" + reader[1] + "\t" + reader[2] + "\t" );
                            Console.WriteLine(Decryptor.DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(@"C:\temp\createCert\TestCertificate.pfx", securePassword, (byte[])reader[2]));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and my Testdecryptor:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
namespace Testbeispiel_Encryption
{
    public class MyDecryptor
    {
        public MyDecryptor()
        {
            //TODO Constructor
        }
        ~MyDecryptor()
        {
            //TODO Destructor
        }
 
        ///<summary>
        ///Opens certificate and private Key, Decrypts Data and returns the decrypted DocID
        ///</summary>
        ///<param name="pfxFilePath">The Filepath to the Certificate (.pfx) File!</param>
        ///<param name="password">The password for accessing the pfx file</param>
        ///<param name="EncryptedDocID">the Value of the encrypted Collumn, Encrypted by the Certifiate of the pfx File</param>
        ///<returns>string DecryptedDocID - the decrypted Value of the DocID</returns>
        public string DecryptDocIDWithFileCert(string pfxFilePath, System.Security.SecureString password, byte[] EncryptedDocID)
        {
            //Reverse the encrypted DocID because SQL reverses the byte array on encryption
            //and so does RSACryptoServiceProvider. 
            Array.Reverse(EncryptedDocID);
            string DecryptedDocID = "";
 
            //load certificate from filesystem and open it with provided password
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath, password);
            if (cert == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Certificate " + pfxFilePath + " Does not exist");
            }
 
            //Check if certificate has a private key, otherwhise we are unable to decrypt any message
            //encrypted with the certs public key so we throw an exception
            if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
                //actualy decrypt message with RSACryptoServiceProvider and set OAEP Padding to false
                //Don't know the reason, otherwhise it didn't work correctly 
                byte[] ret = RsaCSP.Decrypt(EncryptedDocID, false);
                if (ret == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Decryption with RSA failed");
                }
                //Encode DocID to UTF7 String. UTF8 didn't recognise umlauts
                DecryptedDocID = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString(ret);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Certificate " + pfxFilePath + " has no Private Key; ");
            }
            return DecryptedDocID;
        }
    }
}
```

AND FINALY IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Clear Database

```
DROP CERTIFICATE TestCertificate
GO
 
DROP TABLE Encrypt
GO
 
USE master
GO
 
DROP DATABASE TestEncryptionDecryption
GO
```

Comment: I created the certificate, private key and pfx file outside SQL server then when I am trying to create certificate from the file in SQL, it is throwing error.
    Msg 15208, Level 16, State 6, Line 10
The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

Comment: I was able to resolve the above comment, in the syntax of create certificate, it should be "DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD" and not "ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD". Now, I am stuck at another problem, ENCRYPTIONBYCERT return a varbinary of length 500+ and when trying to decrypt in C#, it is throwing error "The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes".